# Geolocation tracking not being asked for permission in chrome on desktop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm running basic code that just outputs the longitude and latitude on the screen or prints an error if something goes wrong.

```
function getMyLocation() {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation, displayError);
    }
    else {
        alert("Oops, no geolaction support");
    }
}

function displayLocation(position) {    
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    var h1 = document.getElementById("location");
    console.log("hey " + latitude + " " + longitude);
    h1.innerHTML += " " + latitude + ", " + longitude;
}

function displayError(error) {
    var errorTypes = {
        0: "unkown error",
        1: "Permission denied by user",
        2: "Position is not available",
        3: "Request timed out"
    };

    var errorMessage = errorTypes[error.code];
    if(error.code == 0 || error.code == 2) {
        errorMessage += " " + error.message;
    }
    var div = document.getElementById("location");
    div.innerHTML = errorMessage;
}
```

When i run in firefox and internet explorer i get pop-ups asking for permission and the code runs fine. When I use my phone's google chrome browser i get asked for permission and everything works fine. When i try chrome on my desktop I never get asked permission and my error code runs and prints: "Permission denied by user".  I've checked in my chrome settings and made sure my hostname is allowed and tried allowing any site to track my physical location but to no avail. What do?

Comment: if you check your console, you should see `getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS` - add `error.message` to `errorMessage` when `error.code == 1` and you'd see it for sure

Comment: @Jarmonanda X I see that error message and when i add: "Https://" in front of my url my page actually works but do you know a way to permanently fix this?

Comment: yes, `use a secure origin, like https` as the error message clearly states